# Bolding Shape Lines in Java

Tags: java, graphics, acm-java-libraries

[image: Bolding the shape lines]

After creating the shape (for example GOval), how can I bold the shape lines?

Comment: To avoid downvotes on your questions in the future, make sure you read and apply the [how-to-ask help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). A classic reply to your question would be: "What have you tried?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such thing as setting a shape line "bold" in the [ACM API](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/student/index.html?acm/program/package-summary.html). What would "bold" be anyway? You would need to specify a "line thickness" value yourself, but I don't think the API caters for this, and there is no default constant for `SHAPE_LINE_BOLD` or similar.

Instead, think about how you can achieve the effect otherwise. `GOval` implements `GFillable`, i.e., you can fill your oval with a specific colour. Perhaps look into overlaying more than one filled shape.

*Hint: If you filled your shape with the same colour as the background, would it be visible?*